# Gnuplot "every" command ignores block restraints

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot 4.6 and I'm trying to plot a single block of data from a file which contains several of them like this:

```
#Z=  0.0000E+00
 -0.6400E+01  0 
 -0.6400E+01  1  


#Z=  0.4000E+00
 -0.6400E+01  0
 -0.6400E+01  2


 #Z=  0.4000E+00
 -0.6400E+01  0
 -0.6400E+01  0.3055E-09


#Z=  0.4000E+00
 -0.6400E+01  0.0000E+00
 -0.6400E+01  3
```

The "stats" command reports correct number of data blocks in file (4 in this case).
According to the gnuplot guide this code should output the last block:

```
plot 'THE_FILE_NAME.DAT' every :::3::3
```

but it results in error message of "x range is invalid" which points at the end of the line instead.

Setting the starting block to the very first one (plot 'THE_FILE_NAME.DAT' every :::0::3) works. But the final block index is ignored (i.e. "plot 'THE_FILE_NAME.DAT' every :::0::0" and "plot 'THE_FILE_NAME.DAT' every :::0::3" both results in all four blocks being plotted).

I really need some insight on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parts of a data file which are separated by *two* blank lines are accessed with `index`:

```
plot 'file.dat' index 3
```

Comment: (sorry, still getting used to site interface)
Well, that solved my problem there, thanks.
I've confused the "datablock" from  [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node61.html#glossary), which is delimited with a single blank line, with "data set" delimited by double blank lines. The latter is mentioned in pdf [guide from gnuplot site](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf) 
Notably, [online version](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node101.html#1935) of this manual avoids mentioning them there altogether presumably to avoid confusion .

Comment: The online manual your linking at is of version 4.2, whereas the pdf is of version 4.6 with a time gap of about 5 years.